# How do I query MySQL into a dictionary using Python?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I am trying to extract my query results into a dictionary in Python, but am not quite sure how to do this.

I have set Dictionary=true in the cursor config but this doesn't seem to work as expected.

```
import mysql.connector as mariadb
#  DB VARIABLES
mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(user='user', password='pass', database='mydb')
cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor(dictionary=True)

cursor.execute("SELECT id, name FROM songs")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
print(rows)
if isinstance(rows, dict):
    print("this IS a dictionary")
```

The code above doesn't print anything.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to get a dictionary, you need to decide what is going to serve as dictionary keys. Assuming it is the first returned field, ie `id`:

```
mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(user='user', password='pass', database='mydb')
cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT id, name FROM songs")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
dic = { t[0]: t[1:] for t in rows }
```

Of course, for this to work correctly values in `id` must be unique.

Comment: The `Id` column should be the unique index for the dictionary. Using the code above, I get back a "too many values to unpack (expected 2). In my real query I have multiple columns and not only `id` and `name`.

Comment: See the changed answer. BTW, giving a misleading example is not the best way to get correct answers.

Comment: It wasn't my intension to mislead, only to simplify the code to isolate the question from the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1):

At you use `.fetchall()` you're going to retrieve multiple result, even if the query has one result, it'll be a `list of all results`.

---

Using `dictionary=True` will give you a list of `dict` with field names like

```
[{'id': '123456', 'name': 'This is the supe song 1'},
 {'id': '456789', 'name': 'This is the supe song 2'},
 {'id': '789123', 'name': 'This is the supe song 3'}]
```

Without `dictionary=True` you'll just get a list of the values as tuples

```
[('123456', 'This is the supe song 1'),
 ('456789', 'This is the supe song 2'),
 ('789123', 'This is the supe song 3')]
```

---

The following is `True` so

```
isinstance(rows, list) # True
isinstance(rows[0], dict) # True
```